# How to allow the path elements in an svg element to overflow the container

Tags: html, css, svg, scaling

I was writing an animation for my logo  ([here](http://codepen.io/samirc/pen/yeRmMw?editors=1100) is the link to the codepen), you can see the code there as well, but I will post here as well.

So I targeted every path element and changed it's properties and everything works fine, except for the fact that since I use the "transform" to move the elements because they leave the container and are hidden.

This is the CSS for the SVG element

```
svg {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  margin-top:100px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 200px);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

I tried adding a `viewbox` inline property to the svg tag but that didn't work either, what can I do? I want every path to be visible no matter where it is, is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `overflow: visible` rule you added to CSS definition for `svg` should have worked.

The reason it didn't was because your SVG also had a `<clipPath>` that had the effect of hiding the overflow.  When you get rid of that also, things behave as you wanted.

[Demo codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVrPdK?editors=1100)

To get rid of the clip, I deleted the `<clipPath></clipPath>` element, and the `clip-path="url(#clipPath20)"` reference from the `<g>`.  Both of these are near the start of the document.

Comment: Thank you so bloody much, you have no idea how helpful you have been, I was searching for so long, nothing worked, thank you.